# Upload file if contains certain name

Tags: filters

I would like to know, if it's possible to filter a file upload by name.
In my case i want that the uploader let me upload the file only if the file name contains the string `"example"`. Ex: `"miimage-example.jpg"`. And deny if does not contains it Ex:"miimage.jpg".

Is there any way to do that? i don't know how Wordpress handless the functions so i'm completely lost.

I will appreciate any help you could provide me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best solution, but it can be considered as a starting point

```
add_filter('sanitize_file_name', 'filter_function_name_11', 10, 2);

function filter_function_name_11($filename, $filename_raw) {  
    $pos = strripos($filename, 'example');
    if ($pos === false) {
       wp_die();
    } else {
        return $filename;
    }
}
```